# I can't send attchment file in wp_mail function

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to send mail with attachment using wp_mail function in that message successfully deliver but not send attachment.so help me for that.
My code as below.

```
$filename = wp_get_attachment_metadata($attchment_id);//Here media file attchment id
       $to = get_user_meta($result->user_id,'billing_email',true);//email id
       $subject = $result->msg_title;//Subject
       $message = $result->msg_body;//HTML message text
       $attachments = array(WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/'.$filename['file'] );//I also try with ABSPATH
       $headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
       $headers[] = 'From: Wordpress ' . "\r\n";
       $sendmail = wp_mail($to, $subject, $message,$headers,$attachments);
```

Comment: Try this:-- `$attachments = array(wp_get_attachment_url($attchment_id));`

Comment: please check you give file is exists or not? because not problem in your syntax.

Comment: Yes there is file in upload directory and i also try `$attachments = array(ABSPATH.'/uploads/2014/05/Jellyfish.jpg');` but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Below code may help you,

```
<?php
    $attachments = array( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/file_to_attach.zip' );
    $headers = 'From: My Name <myname@example.com>' . "\r\n";
    wp_mail('test@example.org', 'subject', 'message', $headers, $attachments );
?>
```

Please see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail for more.

Comment: I already try this but not send mail is there any server setting or wordpress setting for that?

Comment: This code is working fine. May be some server setting is missing.